# Issues with previous operation not finishing

Tags: svn, ubuntu, opencv

I'm fairly new to linux and I'm trying to install the openCV software. I was installing some stuff when I lost power and it was interrupted. When I went to reinstall it, I kept getting this error:

```
svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted
```

So I ran this and tried to restart the download but I got the same error.

```
/opencv$ svn cleanup
/opencv$ svn co https://opencvlibrary.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/opencvlibrary/trunk opencv
svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted
```

I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Does anyone know how to fix this. Please keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: maybe try running cleanup inside the directory you started to check out? `cd /opencv/opencv; svn cleanup`

Comment: That wasn't working either, so I just decided to run the download in a different directory and copied them over. Kind of an archaic way of doing it, but it worked!

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128201/subversion-stuck-due-to-previous-operation-has-not-finished

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I had checked out a few files as root (using sudo) and then tried to run `svn update` again under the user who owned the domain.

Because certain files had ownership and group of root:root, I was unable to update using the user and group that I was logged in under (in this case it was wcl:psacln, psacln being a default group for Plesk users).

To fix the issue, while logged in as root, I simply deleted the file that was causing the issue, ran `svn cleanup`, and then ran `svn up` to get the file back.  Worked like a charm!