# SVN cleanup fails - other posted solutions aren't working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm running tortoiseSVN and I haven't been able to commit or update successfully ever since I interrupted an update (or commit) process a while back. I've found other postings of similar issues, but not of the suggestions are applicable or work - I really need to figure out a way to fix it without starting over.

Details:

- EDIT: Running Windows7
- If I do a commit: it doesn't find files that have changed even though I have.
- If I do an update: 'update failed!' previous operation not finish, run cleanup..
- if I try to cleanup: 
  "Cleanup failed to process the following paths: 
  *the path of the folder I'm trying to cleanup* 
  Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup if it was interrupted 
  Please execute the 'cleanup' command"
- I updated from 1.8.1 to 1.8.4; some problem
- I tried downgrading to 1.7.something; it said something about not being able to update the log or database... went back to 1.8.4
- Nothing is locked, so other suggestions for deleting a lock file doesn't work
- The suggestion here ([What to do when 'svn cleanup' fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158664/what-to-do-when-svn-cleanup-fails)) for deleting the log file doesn't work - I don't have a log file in my .SVN folder.

Anyway to fix this without checking out fresh?

thank you!

Eli

Comment: The Subversion working copy format is not particularly robust. You're lucky for getting error messages: I've had corrupted working copies that had missing files and Subversion would not even warn. In my experience it's just not worth the effort of trying to fix it: renaming current directory, checking out a fresh copy and copying relevant unversioned files and pending changes with your favourite file compare tool is the only way to ensure you have a valid working copy.

Comment: The latest verion (I'm using 1.9.5) solve this problem by adding an option of "Break locks" on the clean up menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the svn meta info on you local workstation got corrupted. I don't see that you can fix this easily until you clean your workspace.

Try this...

1. Back up your folder
2. Delete .svn folder from parent directory and all subdirectories in that folder, or
3. Check out fresh code in the separate directory and ... copy files from the backup folder where you don't have .svn files, so you don't lose your changes.

Comment: I don't see an .ssh folder in any of my  directories. I just have an .svn folder in the checked-out root folder, and in there are two folders (pristine and tmp), and 3 files (entries, format, and wc.db)).

Comment: That worked - thanks!
I just had to make sure that the folder it was checking out too was the same as folders that already existed.

Answer (score 7):

I found a good solution for the same issue on [blog](http://www.anujvarma.com/svn-cleanup-failedprevious-operation-has-not-finished-run-cleanup-if-it-was-interrupted/):

I have tried it and it works fine. In fact I am having source code which is of size more than 3 GB, in this case delete source code after taking backup of changed sources is very difficult. So, found this solution as appropriate to my case.

Comment: Thank you very much. All other solutions involved deleting the SVN folder which is +150gb (don't ask why). But this fix worked for me, and saved me the time of pulling down the source!

Comment: Yeah, I have pass through same situation. Most of the forum answers asks to delete source from local and check out it again. Which is actually expensive solution, when repository source is large in size. Glad this solution helpful to you and hopefully will be helpful to others.

Comment: Best solution by far!

Answer (score 0):

This is much better solution in case you're dug in the depths of your repository structure...just Cleanup a level (or two) higher!

[Subversion stuck due to "previous operation has not finished"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128201/subversion-stuck-due-to-previous-operation-has-not-finished)

Answer (score 0):

1. In Windows 7: Render hidden files visible.
2. Back-up Subversion-Controlled Folder.
3. Check-Out SVN Repository to an empty "New Folder".
4. Delete .svn folder in Subversion-Controlled Folder.
5. Copy .svn Folder from "New Folder" to Subversion-Controlled Folder.
6. Delete "New Folder".
7. In Windows 7: Render hidden files invisible.
8. Delete Back-up of Subversion-Controlled Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just Clear the cache and run again..

To do so : GO to .svn folder (hidden folder in the root) => Go to temp => Delete everything in it :)

Answer (score 0):

Also try running svn cleanup from the command line.

I was just able to use that to resolve the error:  Cleanup failed to process the following paths: .... Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup if it was interrupted. Please execute the 'cleanup' command"